# Chrome dev tools crashing when debugging JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Been googling around a bit for the last week or two and haven't come up with any leads.

I believe this started ever since the latest major chrome web browser update, from 68 to 69. (currently on version 69.0.3497.100 )

Basically, when I'm using the chrome dev tools and debugging some javascript, the browser crashes when I begin typing a variable name into the console. I'll get a character or two in and then **bam**, the whole thing crashes.

[image: dev tools crash warning]

I'll close the browser, reopen it and still crashes immediately when typing in the console. Sometimes there are a few hours in between episodes, but this has been a persistent issue for too long and is severely impacting my ability as a developer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: not sure if that can be answered here, might be better suited on the chromium bugtracker

Comment: I'll go poke around there, thanks

Comment: I've been hitting the same issue on Chrome 69. After doing some digging, I think this bug is related: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=729826

Comment: That does look related. I looked a bit for answers, but didn't find anything useful. I've been so busy with work I just switched to firefox's dev tools. They have their own issues, but at least it's not crashing dozens of times during my workday. Their HTML pane is a bit nicer too

Comment: I also have issues with Chrome 69 & DevTools "quitting" when stepping through code.  Using React/Redux stack.  Had no issues in Chrome 68.  Tried uninstalling React/Redux developer extensions, but would still crash without them installed.

Comment: Any luck with Chrome Beta or Canary?

Comment: simply downgrade back to Chrome 68 ...instead of wasting time with it.

Comment: I have the same issue on several versions, but at last, I understand the issue come from my codes. if you got this crash in devTools console of other website and it is not based on your codes it is a different thing. maybe the crash comes from your device hardware low quality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out on this Reddit post: [Google Chrome 69 Issues](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/9erutb/anyone_seeing_issues_with_chrome_69_performance/), that particular version was riddled with bugs. One website, quoting here from the same reddit thread, titled their article as "**Atrocious** performance - Google Chrome 69".

While this is not a solution, the easiest thing you can do is update to the latest version. (70.0.3538.77, at the time of writing.)